# Switching between 3.3 V and 5 V logic and power supply

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, esp8266, zener

My project involves interfacing an ESP-8266 with a Serial interface that also supplies power.

The trouble is that the serial interface and its logic levels can be initialized at either 3.3 V or 5 V depending on whether it is running in legacy mode or modern.
Sadly this information won't always be known ahead of time as the same cable can switch between both modes depending in the mode in which it starts.

The ESP board can accept direct 3.3 V in, but also has a regulator for USB and 5V in.
The regulator however, accepts 4 - 12 V and would struggle to power the board at 3.3 V.

The board side of the serial must always be 3.3 V however, so I'll be using a level shifter supplied from the 3.3 V pin, as they are not 5 V tolerant.

I'm having a little trouble in creating a circuit to switch between the path that the supply power should take.

I thought a pair of MOSFETs and a Zener calibrated to 4.7 V could work.

Using one inverting for default 3.3 V path, one normal for the 5 V.
The Zener diode would then act as a threshold for switching the MOSFET gates, with a regular diode to tap off from the 5 V line and maintain the gate signal once it's started.

According to the simulation though, this setup won't work:
https://everycircuit.com/circuit/4866371367993344

[image: screenshot of circuit simulation from the included link]

If I could have any pointers or guidance as to where I'm going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Electronics are my hobby, but sadly not my forté.

Comment: (Thanks Velvel for the clean up, I'll aim to adhere more strictly to naming conventions going forward.)

Comment: I'm struggling to make sense of your circuit (morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet). Could you add a brief explanation of how you intend it to work?

Comment: @Minothor (Don't worry, your formatting is far better than the average. I'm just a notorious pedant. And with the schematic, I at least added some value.)

Comment: @brhans I've refined the paragraph a bit, it starts at:"I thought a pair of MOSFETs and a Zener calibrated to 4.7 V could work."

Comment: @Velvel no worries, my day job includes pdf document and ISO standards, you're in good company!

Comment: @brhans even if the initial input voltage is 3.3V?

Comment: For greater clarity - the voltage source is a gameboy advance, but the voltage will be set to 3.3V if a GBA cart is inserted or to 5V if a GB/GBC cart is inserted. As such, both scenarios are possible and unexpected shifts from 3.3V to 5V at startup are also possible.

Comment: Nevermind - I confused the N-MOS/P-MOS symbols - the N-MOS on the right won't always conduct. But the one on the left ... that one will always pass your supply on top through to the bottom-left through its body diode.

Comment: As far as the one on the right - it seems you're forgetting that a real (non-ideal) MOSFET has a non-zero Vgs-th (gate-source threshold voltage), and you're using it as a source-follower, so the voltage at the source pin (output) will be whatever is at the drain pin - minus the Vgs-th of the MOSFET. SO even for a 'logic level' MOSFET you're still going to see at least a 1V drop, and your 'feedback' diode will have no effect since it'll always be reverse-biased.

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266 [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) specifies minimum power supply voltage as 2.5V.

So the simplest solution would be to remove the AMS1117 regulator on the ESP module and replace it with a better one with lower dropout.

When input voltage is too low, bipolar LDOs will tend to saturate their PNP pass transistor and draw extra current, but PMOS based LDOs will turn on the pass transistor fully and basically act like a resistor between input and output. So all you need is a 3.3V PMOS based LDO with a low enough RdsON transistor so the voltage drop when it's in dropout mode will not bother your  ESP8266.

A pin compatible version is [LDL1117](https://file:///home/peufeu/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9chargements/ldl1117.pdf) which has both low dropout and much faster transient response than AMS1117, especially if the tantalum cap is replaced with 10µF ceramic. This will also fix some supply-related crashes which tend to occur on these modules due to the slow transient response of AMS1117 when the micro transitions from sleep to active mode.

If you make your own PCB you can find LDOs with even lower dropout, for example [RP115](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/294/rp115_ea-3158985.pdf) or [XC6220](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/760/TOSL_S_A0010556302_1-2575005.pdf). There are many others, I just did a two minute search filtering on dropout voltage.

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but I'm afraid that this, while helpful, isn't a solution I can implement, hotplate soldering isn't currently available to me and with my hand jitter, replacing the LDO manually is befond my skill level at this time.

Comment: I was hoping to overcome that deficiency by switching the path based on a voltage threshold.

Comment: No need for hot plate, it's possible to remove a SOT223 with a soldering iron (or better, one in each hand). But that does requires a steady hand.